# bayesian logic converse entialment

Tags: probability

In formal epistemology, converse entailment condition states that:

For all e,h and k that are cosistent, if h&k implies e and k does not imply e, then E confirm h relative to k.

Is this justified by a bayesian perspective, where e confirms h relative to k iff P(h/e&k)>P(h/k)?

Comment: Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, yes - the Bayesian approach is a framework for inferring causes from effects. I wouldn't use the word "confirm" unless a posterior probability came out to 0 or 1, though.

If we model E as depending on H so that $P(E|H)>P(E)$, and we model our belief in $H$ as an unknown parameter $p=P(H)$, then observing $E$ will increase our best guess for $p$, in the sense that the posterior distribution for $p$ will be skewed higher than whatever prior distribution we had for it (unless the prior represented no uncertainty to begin with). The same applies when everything is conditioned on some other event $K$.